# ArcPy Cursor iteration update

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to get the cursor to iterate through rows and fields looking for blank or null values and change them to `999999` but it's not changing anything.

```
fc = "C:\Users\\bbrock\Documents\ArcGIS\Ports.shp"

# Create a search cursor 
#
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc) 

# Create a list of string fields
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "", "String")

for row in rows:
    for field in fields:
        if field.type != "Geometry":
            if row.getValue(field.name) == '':
                row.setValue(field.name, '999999')              
                print "%s: Value = %s" % (field.name, row.getValue(field.name))

            if row.isNull(field.name):
                row.setValue(field.name, '999999')              
                print "%s: Value = %s" % (field.name, row.getValue(field.name))
```

Comment: Could you give us a specific question(s) to help you with?

Comment: Accidentally hit the submit button too early, sorry.

Comment: I immediately tried to edit, but someone beat me to it and I couldn't override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a final working copy of my code using  `with arcpy.da.updateCursor as...` as recommended.

```
fc = "C:/Users/bbrock/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Ports_Admin_Join"

fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "", "String")

for field in fields:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field.name) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            if field.type != "geometry" and field.length > 5:
                if row[0] == None or row[0] == ' ':
                    row[0] = '999999'
                    rows.updateRow(row)    
                    print "%s: Value = %s" % (field.name, row[0])
```

Comment: Although this code may work, instantiating a cursor within a loop is terrible for performance.  For the line after checking geometry, the idiomatic way to check for singletons is using `is`, e.g., `row[0] is None`, and the second part isn't checking for an empty string but a string with a single space.

Answer (score 10):

A [SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000050000000) is read-only. You want to use an [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000064000000). Also don't forget to call the cursor's `updateRow` method after setting a row's values.

See [Accessing data using cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) in the help for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You are using arcpy.SearchCursor which is not able to update values. You need to use an arcpy.UpdateCursor. There are a number of other issues with this code but I will just stick to answering your specific question.

Comment: What issues are you referring to?

Comment: It is best practice to utilize a with statement when using cursors. This will make sure that if something goes wrong everything will be disposed of properly (i.e. remove locks, etc.).For example you would want to do this:                 `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "*") as searchCursor:`  
   `for row in searchCursor:`  
       `print row`                                                  Additionally if you are running Arc10.1 or higher arcpy.da is recommended as it is a much faster cursor method.

Comment: Also if you are using ArcGIS 10.1 consider using arcpy.da.updatecursor instead of arcpy.updatecursor for increased performance